# Mount entry in fstab with go

Tags: linux, go, mount, fstab

Is there a way to mount a ssh device with Go using an entry in fstab where the mount options are defined. I have been trying syscall.Mount without success.

```
func main() {

    src := "jeanluc@<remote IP>:/home/jeanluc"
    target := "/home/jeanluc/my-mnt/ursule_jeanluc"
    fs := "fuse.sshfs"

    err := syscall.Mount(src, target, fs, 0, "rw")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

`2018/01/20 11:31:07 operation not permitted exit status 1`

A user mount using the fstab entry works fine.

`sshfs#jeanluc@<remote IP>:/home/jeanluc /home/jeanluc/my-mnt/ursule_jeanluc fuse user,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,follow_symlinks,defaults 0 0`

**Edit:**

Following Marc's advise below here is what worked for me:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mount /home/jeanluc/my-mnt/ursule_jeanluc")

// capture STDOUT
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out

// run cmd
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// print STDOUT
fmt.Printf("%s", out.String())
```

Comment: I run it as suid. When I run it as root i get `invalid argument`. Running it as root is not an option if I can avoid it as I want to have the file permissions for the user. My attempt to use  `os/exec` and `syscall.Exec`  failed also.

Comment: Can you show those attempts as well, including code and output. And the output of a normal `mount` command you want to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your binary either as `root`, or owned by `root` and with the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit.

This is because `/etc/fstab` is used by [`mount (8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) (the command), not [`mount (2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount), so the `user` attribute in your fstab entry does nothing (nor does the rest of the entry).

Indeed, the `mount (2)` man page clearly states:

> Appropriate privilege (Linux: the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) is
>   required to mount file systems.

If you cannot run as a privileged user or want to make use of the `/etc/fstab` entry, you could always [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) the actual mount command.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above, I also failed to use os/exec for some reason. Most probably because of me. I'll keep on trying. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I think there are oddities when using `mount (2)` with fuse. I suggest trying `strace mount ....` and seeing how it invokes `mount`. But yes, getting the `mount (8)` command to work first would be good.

Comment: Working fine now  with `os/exec` calling the mount(8) command.